# how to sort this multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to change output on my shopping cart software.  I believe I have found where the array is coming from and I just need to sort it.  sort() didn't work.  I used print_r to see the array, and it is more dimensions than my small brain can handle.  How to sort this by the full currency name?

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => USD [text] => US Dollar ) [1] => Array ( [id] => EUR [text] => Euro ) [2] => Array ( [id] => GBP [text] => United Kingdom Pound ) [3] => Array ( [id] => CAD [text] => Canadian Dollar ) [4] => Array ( [id] => AUD [text] => Australian Dollar ) [5] => Array ( [id] => CHF [text] => Swiss Franc ) [6] => Array ( [id] => CZK [text] => Czech Koruna ) [7] => Array ( [id] => DKK [text] => Danish Krone ) [8] => Array ( [id] => HKD [text] => Hong Kong Dollar ) [9] => Array ( [id] => HUF [text] => Hungarian Forint ) [10] => Array ( [id] => JPY [text] => Japanese Yen ) [11] => Array ( [id] => NZD [text] => New Zealand Dollar ) [12] => Array ( [id] => NOK [text] => Norwegian Kroner ) [13] => Array ( [id] => PLN [text] => Polish Zloty ) [14] => Array ( [id] => SGD [text] => Singapore Dollar ) [15] => Array ( [id] => SEK [text] => Swedish Krona ) [16] => Array ( [id] => ILS [text] => Israeli New Shekel ) [17] => Array ( [id] => MXN [text] => Mexican Peso ) [18] => Array ( [id] => TWD [text] => Taiwan Dollar ) [19] => Array ( [id] => PHP [text] => Philippine Peso ) [20] => Array ( [id] => THB [text] => Thai Baht ) )
```

Comment: for readability, can you input your Array code on multiple lines in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Interstellar_Coder said, use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort), but do it right!

```
usort($array,create_function('$a,$b','return strnatcasecmp($a["text"],$b["text"]);'));
```

Or, from PHP 5.3 onwards:

```
usort($array,function($a,$b) {return strnatcasecmp($a['text'],$b['text']);});
```

Comment: This is definitely a complete answer +1 for using an anonymous function.

Comment: I have no idea what "Yay for lambdas" means nor do I know what is meant by "anonymous function".  Also, you say "As Interstellar_Coder said" but as far as I see, he didn't say anything until after you answered.

And I assumed I would get a notification so I thought my question was just ignored.  This site is confusing in its operation.

Thanks for the answer though!  I figured something else out but it was nowhere near as elegant.  More readable, perhaps, but less elegant.